# CAML query to retrieve files from Document libraries and Page Library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml, sharepoint-search

I am trying to search in Pages and Document libraries once. Is there a template in CAML that works for both document libraries and pages libraries.

I have this for pages library only but it doesn't search document libraries

```
siteDataQuery.Lists ="<listsLists ServerTemplate=\"850\" />";
```

Full Code

```
 sing (SPWeb web = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Url).OpenWeb())
                {

                    siteDataQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef  Nullable=\"TRUE\" Name=\"FileRef\"/><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>";
                    siteDataQuery.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";
                    siteDataQuery.RowLimit = 500;
                    siteDataQuery.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Recursive\"/>";

                    siteDataQuery.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'Page-Archive Item</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Metadata' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Integer'>447</Value></Eq></And></Where>"

                    System.Data.DataTable dataTable =  web.GetSiteData(siteDataQuery);
                }
```

I need to search every subsites and their respective document and page libraries.

Any ideas??

Comment: you can use like this `siteDataQuery.Lists = “<Lists><List ID=’0f9021b0-77b5-4460-bf5f-b568ae194a00’/><List ID=’0g9025b0-76b5-4680-bf5f-b568ae191b00’/></Lists>”;` where `0f9021b0-77b5-4460-bf5f-b568ae194a00` & `0g9025b0-76b5-4680-bf5f-b568ae191b00` is your list guid, these guid is just an example, see my code.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this for document library:-

```
siteDataQuery.Lists ="< listsLists ServerTemplate=\"101\" />";
```

SharePoint Server Template Id for

> Page Library => 850

and for

> Document library => 101

try to use this `siteDataQuery.Lists` as below

```
siteDataQuery.Lists = "<Lists MaxListLimit=\"2\">" +
              "<List ID="+web.Lists.TryGetList("firstlistname").ID+" />" +
              "<List ID="+web.Lists.TryGetList("secondlistname").ID+" />" +             
           "</Lists>";
```

Hope this will help

Comment: can i specify two list templates in one CAML query. I want to search in  pages librarires and document libraries once

Comment: It's not two lists but can i put to lists template ID here. I will have 3 or 4 document libraries with different names and one or more page libraries too. My idea was to get every items of a content type from all the lists and libraries if present from each sub site.

Comment: You can specify any no of list, just change MaxListLimit=4 & in query append the list info as  I have written for two lists

Comment: If you want to get all list of a specific content type, try this SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
                query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\">";
                query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1' />";
                query.Query = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/><Value Type='Text'>" +
                    "0x0101006d76968475dd473f92fbdec03bbff85e" +
                    "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";

Comment: Replace content type id with your content type id.

Comment: The best way was adding the base template for the lists only                           query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1' />"                                                                      This will search for all the list whose base type is 1 and pages and document libraries have same base type 1

Comment: @user388969 check my comment that is what i had mentioned, probably you missed.